# Using princomp() in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, princomp

I do the following in MATLAB :

```
>> X = [ 123 982 123 ; 434 233 842; 143 239 583; 733 292 503]

X =

123   982   123
434   233   842
143   239   583
733   292   503

[coeff,score] = princomp(X)

coeff =

-0.3714    0.9202    0.1241
 0.7330    0.2085    0.6475
-0.5700   -0.3314    0.7519


score =

 709.3366   26.4384   30.9912
-364.9469  -81.8490  125.1814
-104.8637 -262.5228 -101.7805
-239.5260  317.9334  -54.3921

>> X * coeff

ans =

 603.9913  277.1477  743.6166
-470.2922  168.8604  837.8069
-210.2090  -11.8134  610.8450
-344.8714  568.6428  658.2333
```

Why isn't score = X * coeff ?

I believe X * coeff is the same as projecting the raw data along the principal component axes.

Comment: I believe this is because the coefficients are not orthonormal. Check http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/feature-transformation.html#f75476 for more info

Comment: So should I ideally make them orthonormal first before calculating the projections?

Answer (score 0):

`Xc*coeff` is not equal to `score` because your X is not centered.

As [documentation says](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html),

> princomp centers X by subtracting off column means

Here is what centering does:

```
[m n] = size(X);
Xc = X - kron(ones(m,1),sum(X,1))/m;
```

Output:

```
Xc =

 -235.2500  545.5000 -389.7500
   75.7500 -203.5000  329.2500
 -215.2500 -197.5000   70.2500
  374.7500 -144.5000   -9.7500
```

Observe that

- `[coeff,score] = princomp(Xc)` returns exactly the same result as `[coeff,score] = princomp(X)`.
- `Xc*coeff` is indeed equal to `score`

When using `princomp` you don't have to center data prior to feeding it to princomp since the routine does that for you, and probably in a more efficient way.

(By the way: `princomp` is deprecated; it's recommended to use `pca` instead.)